# How to get and route the numbers of the otp from ng-otp-input using Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ng-otp-input

I created a numeric password form using otp input in page 1 and then on page 2 to confirm password. When I route the password from page 1 to page 2 I get the value of the password as undefined and I cannot modify it into a number because it is a string. How can I get the numbers I input into the otp to be able to route it to the second page?

page1.html

```
<ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" 
                      *ngIf="showOtpComponent"  [config]="{length:6,inputClass:'dot',allowNumbersOnly:true}"></ng-otp-input>

                      <span *ngIf="otp" class="o-t-p"></span>
```

page1.ts

```
export class Page1 {


val: any;

otp: string;
showOtpComponent = true;
@ViewChildren('ngOtpInput') ngOtpInput: any;

  constructor(public router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  onOtpChange(otp) {

    this.otp = otp;

    if (otp.length === 6) {

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/page2/' + this.val);

    }

    }

setVal(val) {
 this.ngOtpInput.setValue(val);
 }




  }
```

page2.html

```
<ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" 
                      *ngIf="showOtpComponent"  [config]="{length:6,inputClass:'dot',allowNumbersOnly:true}"></ng-otp-input>

                      <span *ngIf="otp" class="o-t-p"></span>
```

page2.ts

```
export class page2 {
  val2: any;
  val: string;
  otp: string;
  showOtpComponent = true;
  @ViewChildren('ngOtpInput') ngOtpInput: any;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, public alertController: AlertController) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.val = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("val");
    console.log(this.val);
  }
  onOtpChange(otp) {

    this.otp = otp;
    if (otp.length === 6) {

      this.compare();

      }

    }

setVal(val2) {
 this.ngOtpInput.setValue(val2);
 }





 compare(){
  if(this.val != this.val2){
    this.presentAlert();
  }
  else{
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/page3');
  }
 }
 async presentAlert() {
  const alert = await this.alertController.create({
    header: 'Incorrect Password!!',
    message: 'Please enter the correct password',
    buttons: ['OK']
  });

  await alert.present();
}


}
```

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your router?

Comment: How are you manage to use ng-otp-input module in your ionic page? I keep getting error "if ng-otp-input is a web component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'" to the '@NgModule'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems like in your Page1 you're never setting the value of `val`, therefore an undefined value is sent over the router.
Assuming you want to send the OTP value to Page2, you should modify your `onOtpChange` method in Page1 to the following:

```js
onOtpChange(otp) {
    if (otp.length === 6) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/page2/' + otp);
    }
}
```

Now, in your router (assuming page2 route path is something like `page2/:val`), when you log the route param value you should see it properly displayed:

```js
const val = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("val");
console.log(val);
```